# SDL2 OpenGL 4.2 context with 0 color bits and 0 depth bits

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, sdl-2, glew

I've been trying to start a new SDL + GLEW + OpenGL project, and the setup has been difficult (MinGW-w64-32 on Windows 8 64-bit with an Intel i7-4700MQ CPU and NVidia GTX 745M GPU).

If I set the GL attributes to be used for context creation to use OpenGL version 4.2, the color and depth bit sizes get set to 0. However, if I request a 2.1 context (which is also the default), I can get the requested bit depths (8 bits for each color, 24 bits for depth). In either case, however, glClearColor has no effect (just a black background).

In both cases, the result of a few `glGetString` calls is the same- a 4.2 context, suggesting SDL's output is far from correct.

The entirety of the code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/C71uqJ5m), it's mostly boilerplate for a larger project for now. The relevant sections would most likely be

```
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
    std::cerr << "Error initializing SDL.\n";
    exit(1);
}

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);
//SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_FLAG);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("RenderSystem", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL|SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

if(!window) {
    std::cerr << "Window creation failed.\n";
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(2);
}

SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

if(!context) {
    std::cerr << "OpenGL Context creation failed.\n";
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(3);
}

SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, context);
```

and

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

SDL_Event evt;
bool run = true;

while(run) {

    SDL_PollEvent(&evt);

    switch(evt.type) {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            if(evt.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
                run = false;
            }
            break;

        case SDL_QUIT:
            run = false;
            break;
    }

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

}
```

Comment: How are you determining said values? In OpenGL 3.0, it is not valid to query `GL_RED_BITS`, `GL_DEPTH_BITS`, etc. on the default framebuffer. A compatibility profile should deliver consistent results, but core profiles have different behavior.

Comment: You don't seem to call `glClear()` anywhere.  `glClearColor()` just latches some state, it doesn't actually clear any buffers.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I'm using SDL's built-in function `SDL_GL_GetAttribute` which returns the values that SDL uses to create the context, not the actual context attributes (as I understand it).

Comment: @genpfault I was worrying more about the 0 values from the `SDL_GL_GetAttribute` calls, and completely skipped over that. That does solve the issue of course for the 2.1 context request that allows me to set the values for the bit depths, and also oddly solves the issue for a 4.2 context, even though SDL still reports the zero-bit buffer depths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using SDL's built-in function `SDL_GL_GetAttribute` which returns the values that SDL uses to create the context, not the actual context attributes (as I understand it).

This is incorrect, I took a look at the SDL implementation of `SDL_GL_GetAttribute (...)` (see [`src/video/SDL_video.c`](https://github.com/zielmicha/SDL2/blob/master/src/video/SDL_video.c)) and it does what I described. You cannot query the values on a core profile context because they are not defined for the default framebuffer.

#### Here is where the problem comes from:

```
int
SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GLattr attr, int *value)
{
  // ...

  switch (attr) {
  case SDL_GL_RED_SIZE:
    attrib = GL_RED_BITS;
    break;
  case SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE:
    attrib = GL_BLUE_BITS;
    break;
  case SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE:
    attrib = GL_GREEN_BITS;
    break;
  case SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE:
    attrib = GL_ALPHA_BITS;
    break;
  }

  // ...

  glGetIntegervFunc(attrib, (GLint *) value);
  error = glGetErrorFunc();
}
```

That code actually generates a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error on a core profile, and the return value of `SDL_GL_GetAttribute (...)` should be non-zero as a result.

If you must get meaningful values from `SDL_GL_GetAttribute (...)` for bit depths, then that means you must use a compatibility profile. SDL2 does not extract this information from the pixel format it selected (smarter frameworks like GLFW do this), but it naively tries to query it from GL.

Answer (score -3):

If not fail me memory, SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE has to be the sum of all color channels:

using four color channels:

`SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 32);`

If you were using 3 color channels would then:

`SDL_GL_SetAttribute (SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);`

Already had some problems with it, this might be the problem.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: The depth buffer precision has nothing to do with the color channels. You might confuse with with the combined depth/stenctil buffer, which typically provides 24 bit depth and 8 bit stencil.